# Remove word from string start with specific characters

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

I have the following string:

```
my_string = "This is an example string, ex , excatly , index , hyperextension"
```

I want to remove all words that start with `ex` in Python.

So the result I want would be:

```
remove_words_that_start_with_ex("my_string")
print(my_string)
```

Desired result:

> This is an string, , , index , hyperextension

I tried doing something like this:

```
main_str = " ".join(filter(lambda x:x[0,1]!='ex', main_str.split()))
```

but it only works with one character, not 2 ("ex").

Comment: Use `x[:2]` instead of `x[0,1]`, or `x.startswith('ex')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to do this

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string = "This is an example string, ex , excatly , index , hyperextension"
>>> re.sub('(?:\s)ex[^, ]*', '', my_string)
'This is an string, , , index , hyperextension'
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the sentence starts with a word starting with 'ex'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's built-in [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method like so:

```
>>> my_string = "This is an example string, ex , excatly , index , hyperextension"
>>>
>>> print ' '.join(x for x in my_string.split() if not x.startswith('ex'))
This is an string, , , index , hyperextension
```

Now in case you just want to fix your lambda, here is a fix:

```
>>> print " ".join(filter(lambda x: x[0:2]!='ex', my_string.split()))
This is an string, , , index , hyperextension
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
my_string = "This is an example string, ex , excatly , index , hyperextension"
final_string = re.sub('(?<=\s)ex[\w]+|(?<=^)ex[\w]+', '', my_string)
```

Output:

```
'This is an  string, ex ,  , index , hyperextension'
```

Or, by providing a `lambda`:

```
final_string = re.sub('\w+', lambda x:'' if x.group().startswith('ex') else x.group(), my_string)
```

Output:

```
'This is an  string,  ,  , index , hyperextension'
```

Comment: Hi, I didn't downvote (_if I did I would have explained why_) but just noticed that your first snippet using `re` keeps the `ex` word which should be removed. The lambda works fine though!

Comment: Also If you want to use `re.sub` you could change the regexp e.g. to `(?<=\s)ex[\w]*[\s*]`